# Custom Y-Axis in AnyChart

Tags: javascript, node.js, anychart, anychart-8.2

I have a requirement where the y-axis labels need to be the following:
1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0

Is there a way to achieve this custom y-axis in AnyChart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less possible. You can set the desired logarithmic scale with these settings:

```
var logScale = anychart.scales.log();
logScale.minimum(0);
logScale.maximum(1);

// Get ticks
var ticks = logScale.ticks();
ticks.count(4);

// Minor ticks
var minorTicks = logScale.minorTicks();
minorTicks.count(3);

chart.yScale(logScale);
chart.yAxis({minorTicks: true, minorLabels: true});
```

However, as far as I know, it is not possible to jump from 0.001 to 0. This happens because internally the from 0.001 to 0 there is a big gap of numbers that we can't just skip while keeping the chart scale consistent.

[image]

Demo: https://playground.anychart.com/CnDenhWb/2

On the other hand if you really wish to show only `[1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0]`, then you can add this code:

```
var ticksArray = [1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0];
chart.yScale().ticks().set(ticksArray);
```

This will hide other labels in between 0.001 and 0.

Demo: https://playground.anychart.com/ABxQ3oBc/1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using the only logScale with applied manually required ticks. For details, check [the sample on the playground](https://playground.anychart.com/0Zk9ZJX1/1).
Below is the result:
[image]